# How to Read Data From a children array of a JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift5, swift4.2

here is my json

```
let myjson = """
{
  "name": "md",
  "student": "cse",
  "project":[{
    "id": "1",
    "pname":"iOS"
  },{
    "id": "2",
    "pname":"adroid"
  }],
}
"""
```

from this json I want to print a specific data in my swift playground program

I want to print only this data

```
{
"id": "1",
"pname":"iOS"
}
```

[here is an image of what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJgsi.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode your json and encode to new jsonString:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var project: [Project]
}

struct Project: Codable {
    var id: String
    var pname: String
}

// your json string
let myjson = """
{ "name": "md", "student": "cse", "project":[{ "id": "1", "pname":"iOS" },{ "id": "2", "pname":"adroid" }]}
"""
let data = myjson.data(using: .utf8)!
let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
   
// encode to print new json string
let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(response)
let jsonString = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)
print(jsonString)
```

Comment: is it possible to print only I info from here ? 
just this section. 


{
"id": "1",
"pname":"iOS"
}

Comment: Yes, because it decodes only `id`and `pname` in `"project"`data.. You can check what `print(jsonString)` prints or modify the model.